# Optimistic Concurrency Issue and Improving Solutions

Tags: .net, vb.net, sql-server-2005

In our database we have gigantic tables (it was initially built 20 years ago). We are on the process of developing it.

Some tables contain `rowversion` and optimistic concurrency. We were wondering if there is a way to just correspond `rowversion` to the modification of some *specific* columns, but not all of them. In Normal Case, T-SQL which is generated then would be huge.

Any Suggestions?

Comment: I've worked on a distributed system that grew over 0.5 TB/day (which is not exactly out there, when it comes to distributed system loads). Are you talking bigger than that?

Comment: No, less than that. Anyway, who cares about Size, I was caring about the amount of autoamtic generated T-SQL which on my point of view in unnecessary! gush! can u describe the functionality of that system? Was it building a HIDROGENIC BOMB OR SOMETHING?

Comment: It was the data mining engine on live search (I left shortly before it became Bing).

Answer (score 1):

What is the method it is using where `rowversion` is used for `optimistic locking`?

The standard trick is to read the `rowversion` when you read the row values. Later, when UPDATEing, you ensure that the `rowversion` in the database matches the rowversion when you last saw. If not, then you know someone else modified the row out of underneath you:

```
UPDATE Customers
SET Firstname = 'Faulty', Lastname = 'Orc', ...
WHERE CustomerID = 624429
AND rowversion = @rowversion
```

You only need to update the columns you want to update.

Is it that perhaps you *want* multiple people to independently make changes to the same row? In that case, no, you cannot do that.